# How to get the original requested URI from JAX-RS javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am trying to write a custom `ExceptionMapper` class for JAX-RS. I would like to read somehow the original requested URI from the JAX-RS `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` object.

When I check the response object with IntelliJ IDEA in debug mode then I can see this info under the following path: response > context > resolvedUri where
 type of the `context` is [`org.glassfish.jersy.client.ClientResponse`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientResponse.java). This class has a `resolvedUri` variable which holds the info I need.

Can I get this info somehow? How I can write my `getRequestUri(response)` method?

```
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException error) {

        Response response = error.getResponse();
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = ErrorResponseBuilder
                .builder()
                .httpStatus(getDefaultStatusCodeIfNull(response))
                .errorMessage(getCustomErrorMessage(response))
                .requestedUri(getRequestedUri(response)) <--------- HOW TO READ IT?
                .build();

        return Response
                .status(errorResponse.getHttpStatus())
                .type(ExtendedMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .entity(errorResponse)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `URI uri = response.getLocation(); System.out.println(uri.toString());` ?

Comment: I have tried. It returns with null :(

Comment: Not sure but as Java [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#getLocation--) it returns the location URI otherwise null if **not present**.

Comment: `getLocation()` return the Uri in the location header in case of a redirect 302 code for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

> @Context
>   private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

And use `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()`

```
public class MyExceptionMapper implements 
     ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException> {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException error) {

        Response response = error.getResponse();
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = ErrorResponseBuilder
                .builder()
                .httpStatus(getDefaultStatusCodeIfNull(response))
                .errorMessage(getCustomErrorMessage(response))
                .requestedUri(servletRequest.getRequestURI())
                .build();

        return Response
               .status(errorResponse.getHttpStatus())
               .type(ExtendedMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
               .entity(errorResponse)
               .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a perfect solution. Works like a charm. Thx. The only one remained question is related to multithread envoronment. How parelell request calls to same rest URI with (for example) different headers are handled? Does each paralell request has a own instance of MyExceptionMapper class with the belonged request object?

Comment: @Context is Request Scoped so there will be a unique one for each request.